# CLT probability of drawing 50 tickets

Tags: probability

Question:
A lottery ticket has these paremeters: ($X$ is the amount of winnings from the ticker)
$E[X]=0$, $V(X)=100$

Someone draws 50 tickets randomly, what is the probability that the average of all the winnings will be bigger than 15?

Tried: 
Using the CLT I got the answer was 0, but this seems fishy to me for some reason. Would like to verify.
Thx

Comment: You are right to be suspicious. The answer you give is clearly wrong. You could win the lottery each time, giving average winnings greater than 15, so the probability is nonzero. The Central Limit Theorem is a statement about the limit as $n\rightarrow \infty$ of the average of the first $n$ terms, not a statement about $n=50$.

Comment: Could you then give me a full solution? I'm kinda stuck with how to do it.

Comment: Is X assumed to be normally distributed ?

Comment: Assume we cannot loose money on a ticket, denote each ticket by $X_i$ and denote $Z=1/50 \sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i$ then $EZ=0$ and if furthermore tickets are independent then $Var(Z)=100/50$ by Chebyshev $P(Z\geq 15)\leq Var(Z)/15^2 =0.00888..$. This is probably not the sought, but I thought it was funny :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper answer is probably "we don't know". The distribution of lottery winnings has a *very* heavy tail (colossal winnings in extremely rare cases), which is not conducive for convergence of averages to the normal distribution.

Let $Z=\frac{1}{50}\sum_{i=1}^{50} X_i$. Following the comment by [Henrik](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/584403/clt-probability-of-drawing-50-tickets#comment1235402_584403) (where there is no need to assume that $X\ge 0$, which can't be true anyway), we get $$P(Z\ge 15)\le \frac{100}{50\cdot 15^2}=\frac{2}{225}<0.01$$
from Chebyshev's inequality.

But if this is a textbook problem, there is also a chance that you are expected to assume CLT applies, calculate the $z$-score for $15$ ($z=\frac{15}{\sqrt{100/50}}>10$), and conclude - as you did - that the probability is so very close to $0$ that reporting it as $\approx 0$   makes perfect sense.